# Algorithm to find all possible values of A^5 + B^5 + C^5?

Tags: java, algorithm

im trying to write an algorithm that will find all the possible values of A^5 + B^5 + C^5 when the user inputs a number 'N'.

For example if N=100 I want to make an array that contains all the possible values where each slot in the array contains a number that was found by plugging in numbers between 1-100 for A^5 + B^5 + C^5. So one of the positions in the array contains 1 from (1^5 + 1^5 + 1^5). Another position in the array contains 
the number 355447518 (from 19^5 + 43^5 + 46^5). So there will be 100^3 elements in my array.

```
public long[] possibleValues(int n)
{

    long[] solutionSet = new long[(int) Math.pow(n, 3)];

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        solutionSet[i] = ((long) Math.pow(i, 5) + (long) Math.pow(i, 5) + (long) Math.pow(i, 5));

       //testing purposes
        System.out.println(i +"^5 " + "+" + i+"^5 " + "+" + i+"^5" + "=" + solutionSet[i]);
    }


    return solutionSet;
}
```

thats what I have so far, but my problem is that it doesn't do all the permutations of N. What is the best way to get all possible permutations of N? Am i making this more complicated than necessary? How would I arrange all possible (A, B, C)'s ?

Comment: Math.pow is very expensive, you are better off writing your own powerOf5 method. To do all the permutations, you can do nested loops.  BTW you can assume that A <= B <= C to reduce the number of permutations.

Comment: Are you assuming that `1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5` is different from `3^5 + 2^5 + 1^5`?

Comment: Are triplets where the powers or the summation wrap allowed as solutions?

Comment: prepare an array with computed values i^5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `i` for all 3 terms, thus you're essentially calculating permutations of
`A^5 + A^5 + A^5 = 3A^5`.

You need a 3-dimensional array and 3 for loops.

```
public long[][][] possibleValues(int n)
{
    long[][][] solutionSet = new long[n+1][n+1][n+1];

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
    for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)
    {
        solutionSet[i][j][k] = ((long) Math.pow(i, 5) + (long) Math.pow(j, 5) + (long) Math.pow(k, 5));

       //testing purposes
        System.out.println(i +"^5 " + "+" + j+"^5 " + "+" + k+"^5" + "=" + solutionSet[i][j][k]);
    }

    return solutionSet;
}
```

If you indeed only want a 1-dimensional array, you'll do something similar to the above, just have a separate variable for the index:

Since you probably don't want excessive repetition of values, you can probably start `j` from `i` and `k` from `j`.

```
public long[] possibleValues(int n)
{
    long[] solutionSet = new long[n*n*n];

    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for(int j = i; j <= n; j++)
    for(int k = j; k <= n; k++)
    {
        solutionSet[c] = ((long) Math.pow(i, 5) + (long) Math.pow(j, 5) + (long) Math.pow(k, 5));

       //testing purposes
        System.out.println(i +"^5 " + "+" + j+"^5 " + "+" + k+"^5" + "=" + solutionSet[c]);
        c++;
    }

    return solutionSet;
}
```

Some significant optimizations can still be done:

- `Math.pow` isn't particularly efficient, as Peter mentioned.
- For the first version, you can derive values from previous values in certain circumstances.

Comment: @Shoe I was hoping that was understandable enough as it stood. I can argue technicalities, but never mind. Edited.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your first sentence. `3A^5` doesn't generated the same set as `A^5 + B^5 + C^5`. It generates a subset where A=B=C

Comment: @Shoe Well, the code is calculating `i^5 + i^5 + i^5`, which is `3i^5`. Just replacing `i` with `A`, you get `3A^5`. Here A=B=C (=i).

Comment: The case where A=B=C is 100/1000000 cases and you don't consider that in your algorithm anyway. I'm confused why you mention it at all.

Comment: @Shoe Because that's the only cases the code in the question is considering.

Comment: I don't think this offers an answer to "What is the best way to get all possible permutations of N?". It doesn't take into account any pre-calculated values.

Comment: I see now, I didn't understand you were referencing the asker's code. @Zahnon "best" is ambiguous, and caching values isn't necessarily "better" in certain applications. It certainly won't improve the algorithm itself.

Comment: @Dukeling I believe the issue is confusion. He's asking for distinct values for A, B, and C. That's why there are three different variables. He did not ask for 3*A^5.

Comment: @Shoe Yes, the question is vague. However, in my experience, programs that run faster are more likely to be used and re-used.

Comment: @Zahnon But it does tell OP what's wrong with his/her code, says how to fix it, and gives code where the issues are fixed. I believe "the best way" would probably be too complicated, based on the question.

Comment: @Dukeling Fair enough. I believe StackOverflow has a rule about arguing opinionated questions. I'll keep mine to myself.

Comment: @Zahnon caching values isn't an improvement on the algorithm, it's an improvement on the implementation of powers. Since the question asks for an algorithm, powers optimization is a sidenote

Comment: @Shoe The algorithm is the entire implementation. Programmers that ignore the big picture tend to be sloppy and write bad code. Oh, I'm getting sucked into this opinion thing again.

Comment: Haaaa,  Lovely!! I love you very much

Comment: hey the array size is 171700 do you know why? I would have thought the array size would have been 100^3

Comment: @Steven It's because `j` starts from `i` and `k` starts from `j`. The rest are all duplicate values (e.g. `1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 = 3^3 + 2^3 + 1^3`). If you want these to be in the output you can just replace `j = i` with `j = 0` and `k = j` with `k = 0`.

Comment: @Dukeling hmm i dont really understand why the array size is 171700 is there some way to determine that with a formula - given an 'n' ? similar to how it would be w/o replacement: n*n*n (when n=100: 100*100*100)?

Comment: @Steven [This](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/time-complexity-of-a-triple-nested-loop) should explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Use nested forloops:

```
index=0;
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
  for (int j=1;i<=n;j++){
    for (int k=1;i<=n;k++){

       solutionSet[index++] = ((long) Math.pow(i, 5) + (long) Math.pow(j, 5) + (long) Math.pow(k, 5));
    }
  }
}
```

You can calculate all powers quicker by using an array containing all fifth powers up to N.

Comment: This calculates permutations, not combinations.

Comment: Yes, that's   what he was asking for (he said there should be 100^3 elements in his set), if you want the unique results put them in a set.

Comment: The original question is poorly written. It's good to note what your algorithm does. That's what I did by my comment. Adding to a set is work that doesn't need to be done if you optimize your loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use three loops. One each for A, B, C. This is a pseudo code and does not adhere to java syntax

```
for(int A:100){
  for(int B:100){
     for(int C:100) {
         calculate A^5 * B^5 * C^5
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The really brute-force way to do it would require three nested loops:

```
for(int a = 1; a <= n; ++a)
{
    for(int b = 1; b <= n; ++b)
    {
        for(int c = 1; c <= n; ++c)
        {
            // Add this combination to your array, and print it out.
            // It may be more convenient to use ArrayList instead of long[].
        }
    }
}
```

Note that for this takes O(n^3) time, so n doesn't have to be very large before it will take forever to compute (and also use up all of your memory).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers about nested forloops. For better performance it may be profitable to store the answers in a hash table so that you don't recalculate the same value. For instance, you calculate 15^5 then you store that answer in an array like ans['155'] = 759375. So when you go to calculate 15^5 again you can do an if statement if(ans[num.tostring+'5']) then use that value instead of calculating 15^5 again.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Dukeling previous answer:
I use a `powers` array to compute the powers just `n` times (not `n*n*n`)

```
public static void test(int n){
    long[] powers = new long[n+1];
    for (int i=0; i<powers.length; i++)
        powers[i] = (long) Math.pow(i, 5);

    long[][][] solutionSet = new long[n+1][n+1][n+1];

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)
            {
                solutionSet[i][j][k] = ((long) powers[i] + (long) powers[i] + (long) powers[i]);

               //testing purposes
                System.out.println(i +"^5 " + "+" + j+"^5 " + "+" + k+"^5" + "=" + solutionSet[i][j][k]);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a combination and not a permutation. It also seems that you want A, B, and C to be all possible values from 1 to N. In that case, you'll want to make your nested for loop as such to only calculate the combinations:

```
for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b <= a; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= b; c++) {
            pow5(a) + pow5(b) + pow5(c);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also want to use a lookup table which could be loaded from a file. The more values in your lookup table, the faster your algorithm will perform. In my opinion, the best method will reduce the number of operations required. That means not calculating every value at runtime. Alternatively, you could also optimize for memory usage and just use a simple algorithm. Additionally, you'll want to measure the performance of the algorithm. Here is an example.

```
// for all number > 0 and <= 25
public static final double[] powersOf5 = {1.0, 32.0, 243.0, 1024.0, 3125.0,
7776.0, 16807.0, 32768.0, 59049.0, 100000.0, 161051.0, 248832.0, 371293.0,
537824.0, 759375.0, 1048576.0, 1419857.0, 1889568.0, 2476099.0, 3200000.0,
4084101.0, 5153632.0, 6436343.0, 7962624.0, 9765625.0};

// calc pow(i, 5) and use a lookup table for small values i
public static double pow5(int i) {
    if (i > 0 && i <= 25) {
        return powersOf5[i-1];
    } else {
        return Math.pow(i, 5);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(pow5(i));
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Execution time: " + (end - start) + " ms");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**have a think at first**

```
1. 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 = 3^5 + 2^5 +1^5 , So i<j<k
 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  for(j=i;j<N;j++)
    for(k=j;k<N;k++)


2.  A^5+B^5+C^5=D^5+E^5+F^5
    If we use array , there may be lots of same value in it.
    we can use Set to save memory, if time is not the most important.

3.  A^5 cannot be saved by Long type, when A is too big.
    So, do we make sure N is little? otherwise, there may be a bug.

4.  Multiplication cost lots of time.
    Give a example, if N=100, to get all result, how many times does it spend
    calc 5^5.
    5^5+1^5+1^5
    5^5+1^5+2^5
    5^5+1^5+3^5
    ...
    How about if there is an array save the answer
    define array[i] = i^5
    Then it save our time;
```

Just think more, Algorithm is something that like this

---

Now let's talk more about Math.pow();

Yes it's a good method that help you, but this is an algorithm which is impl, we just want to know A^5, not A^N, the second parameter is static;

Why not  impl a method by yourself.

First, we try to impl a method like this

```
public Long powOf5(Long A){
   return A*A*A*A*A;
}
```

Then, we find we can optimize it.

```
public Long powOf5(Long A){
   Long A2 = A*A;
   return A2*A2*A;
}
```

This multiply 3 times, that multiply 4 times;

I am sure this method is faster than Math.pow()

Comment: If A2 = A*2, then A2*A2*A = (2*A)(2*A)*A = (4*A^2)*A = 4*A^3 != A^5

Comment: I am sorry , My mistake, it should be A*A = A^2